# searchDisplayController message sent to deallocated instance (only in iOS7)

Tags: ios7, exc-bad-access, searchdisplaycontroller

This is my code in `AppDelegate`

```
iMapView = [[iMapViewController alloc] init];
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
            iMapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);
        }
    }

    [viewController.view addSubview:iMapView.view];  // crashing here
```

I turn on NSZombie and found the problem:

```
[iMapViewController searchDisplayController]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xd81d740
```

But i have never ever use `searchDisplayController` or its delegate anywhere.

```
@interface iMapViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

It only happen in iOS 7 with non-ARC.

Could you please give me some advice?

Thank you

Comment: check xib, how did you created iMapViewController? like copy paste from other class or created new one from file->newFile

Comment: I create my view from code, my xib is blank

Comment: what is your xib name, put your xib name in your code..

Comment: i used "iMapView = [[iMapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"iMapViewController" bundle:nil];" but nothing changed

Comment: once do this iMapViewController *newObject = [[iMapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"iMapViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: I did not see crash any more. What's happen if iMapView is global variable? Why did it crash

Comment: how are you declaring your variable, put your code.

Comment: @interface ContentAppIpadAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {iMapViewController    *iMapView;}

Comment: may be you are releasing and then accessing your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once do this, don't make a global instance of your view controller.

```
iMapViewController *newObject = [[iMapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"iMapViewController" bundle:nil];
```

May be you are releasing your iMapView and accessing it again.